# How to add additional scenes to a Stage in JavaFx 2.0

Tags: javafx-2

I have a web application where users log on to the site in the main page, once they are logged in I would like to display a different "page" or scene. How can I change the scene that is being displayed currently in the stage without creating additional windows? All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scene page2 = new Scene(new Group(new Text(25,25,"Page 2!")));
stage.setScene(page2);
```

Comment: Sweet thanks Sergey, I had to move some things around but I was able to create the second page and link as you told me.